# Different Cluster to Different Layers in the same Map

Tags: drupal-7, openlayers, drupal-views

I have a map showing two different kind of projects, National projects and Regional Projects. Each type of project is in a different layer, made with views, but shown in the same map. I would like to apply a different cluster to each layer, e.g. National projects cluster in green and with a distance of 5px, Regional Projects cluster in blue and with a distance of 20px.

I also would like the two layers not to mix between them, meaning the regional layers should not cluster with the national one.

I am using Drupal 7, openlayers 2.0beta-7

Is this possible?

Thank you!!

Solution:

Finally I decided to go the easy way and I added a custom behavior called custom_cluster so I can a apply a different one to each layer.

Comment: Don't suppose you can set up a JSFiddle with what you have so far? or at least post the relevant code. Otherwise I've got to build a project from scratch to try to work out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question, then I think you can do something like this: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster-extended.html

Generally, cluster strategies are defined at the level of the vector layer, so having two separate ones within one map view could also be achieved by adding two different vector layers, each with their own markup and clustering strategy.

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what I was looking for and I had no idea of where to start!!I did some research but I didn't find it... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lucia Please manually click the little bounty icon on the left of John's answer to award the bounty you set on this question. Just accepting the answer won't award the bounty (although the system technically will award the bounty when it expires, it's preferable to manually award it).